# How to select results in a row range in HQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, hql

I am using an oracle dbms and my working query is:

```
SELECT * from 
 (
  select m.*, rownum r
  from Mytable m where m.status in ('PUBLISHED')
 )
where r >= 2  and r < 7;
```

I tried to translate it in HQL:

```
from 
(
 select m, rownum r
  from Mytable m where m.status in ('PUBLISHED')
 )
 where r >= :start  and r < :end;
```

but it gives me an error regarding the first "(".

What am I doing wrong?

edit:
in the end I went for a native query but it gives me "invalid column name", that is because I am using the "m" alias. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: What is the error its giving?

Comment: Unexpected token "(" at column... , in other words HQL doesn't like the from (select... part

Comment: I assume the missing select statement in your uploaded HQL is a typo?

Comment: I decided for a native query but I am still getting problems...could you check it out?

Comment: Update your question with the query.

Comment: It's the first one I wrote in this topic, the one written in SQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71175/discussion-between-mmmmmpie-and-phate).